# What happens to a SQL Server 2005 table with an identity (int) that goes over maxint?

Tags: sql-server

For example, will SQL Server warn you or does it just die?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 will throw the following error when you overflow the IDENTITY column.

```
Server: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

Your identity column need not be constrained to an INT and indeed can be set to BIGINT if you suspect that INT will not be large enough.

INT (32-bit signed) will go up to 2,147,483,647 and BIGINT (64-bit signed) to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (that's 9 quintillion, enough for 1.3 billion id's per person on the planet).

Answer (score 0):

It would likely do both.